# How to clear variable in for loop

Tags: string, loops, append

This program is to generate 100 random 4 letter numbers, it starts by generating 4 letters, but then generates 4 more and adds them to the function. Im guessing it is because i used .append. I tried putting in random = ""; at the top and bottom of the loop but it just cleared the variable. Is there any other way i can do this, or is there anything i can add to the program?

```
    Random input = new Random();
    StringBuilder in = new StringBuilder();

    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklomnpqrstuvwxyz";
    char[] letterPool;
    letterPool = alphabet.toCharArray();
    for(int y = 0; y < 101; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x<4; x++){
        in.append(alphabet.charAt(input.nextInt(alphabet.length())));

    }

    String random=in.toString();


    System.out.println(random);

    System.out.println("space");
    }
```

Comment: Huh?? < pad pad pad >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Random input = new Random();
String alphabet = "abcdefghijklomnpqrstuvwxyz";
for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
    StringBuilder in = new StringBuilder();
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        in.append(alphabet.charAt(input.nextInt(alphabet.length())));

    }
    String random = in.toString();
    System.out.println(random);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Why does moving the StringBuilder between the for loops solve it?

Comment: By doing so, in each iteration of  outer `for` loop, `StringBuilder` will be re-initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The inner for loop will reset itself each time the outer for loop finishes.